# ¿Cómo poner place holder a un EditText en Android?

Tags: android

Por defecto un **EditText** no muestra nada pero quisiera que mostrara algunos ejemplos de lo que se debe ingresar poniéndole un place holder, que es un texto que se "borra" en cuanto se empieza a escribir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el `xml` donde tengas el `EditText` simplemente puedes agregarle la propiedad `hint`

```
android:hint="Hola soy un placeholder para android"
```

También puedes hacerlo directamente desde el código mediante el método [`setHint(int)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setHint(int)), que recibe por parámetro un *"resource id of a string"* o una cadena de texto literal

```
myEditText.setHint("Hola, soy un placeholder para android");
```

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la propiedad [`android:hint`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:hint) del EditText:

```
<EditText 
...
android:hint="Escribe algo!"/>
```

Programaticamente también se puede realizar,

```
 myEditText.setHint("Escribe algo!");
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> **android:hint** : Texto de sugerencia para mostrar cuando el texto está
>   vacío.